# Group by date range , count and sort within each group LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of dates stored in my object. This is sample data. In real time, the dates will come from a service call and I will have no idea what dates and how many will be returned:

```
var ListHeader = new List<ListHeaderData>
{
    new ListHeaderData
    {
        EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 8, 26)
    },
    new ListHeaderData
    {
        EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 11)
    },
    new ListHeaderData
    {
        EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1)
    },
    new ListHeaderData
    {
        EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 15)
    },
    new ListHeaderData
    {
        EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 17)
    },
    new ListHeaderData
    {
        EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 5)
    },
};
```

I now need to group by date range like so:

```
Today (1) <- contains the date 9/17/2013 and count of 1
within 2 weeks (3) <- contains dates 9/15,9/11,9/5 and count of 3
More than 2 weeks (2) <- contains dates 8/26, 1/1 and count of 2
```

this is my LINQ statement which doesn't achieve what I need but i think i'm in the ballpark (be kind if I'm not):

```
var defaultGroups = from l in ListHeader
                group l by l.EntryDate into g
                orderby g.Min(x => x.EntryDate)
                select new { GroupBy = g };
```

This groups by individual dates, so I have 6 groups with 1 date in each. How do I group by date range , count and sort within each group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Introduce array, which contains ranges you want to group by. Here is two ranges - today (zero days) and 14 days (two weeks):

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var ranges = new List<int?> { 0, 14 };
```

Now group your items by range it falls into. If there is no appropriate range (all dates more than two weeks) then default `null` range value will be used:

```
var defaultGroups = 
      from h in ListHeader
      let daysFromToday = (int)(today - h.EntryDate).TotalDays
      group h by ranges.FirstOrDefault(range => daysFromToday <= range) into g
      orderby g.Min(x => x.EntryDate)
      select g;
```

UPDATE: Adding custom ranges for grouping:

```
var ranges = new List<int?>();
ranges.Add(0); // today
ranges.Add(7*2); // two weeks
ranges.Add(DateTime.Today.Day); // within current month
ranges.Add(DateTime.Today.DayOfYear); // within current year
ranges.Sort();
```

Comment: Based on the OP's comments it seems that the groupings of days aren't exclusively in a fixed number of days, i.e he mentions the last month, which is a variable number of days.

Comment: @Servy thanks, I haven't seen yet OP comments to other answers. Let me check that.

Comment: @Servy I don't see any problem to fill ranges list with any value OP needs. E.g. for currentMonth you should add `DateTime.Today.Day` to list. Also if it's unknown what ranges will be added, then ranges list should be sorted before querying.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - I really like this approach, but how do i sort the individual groups asc/desc?

Comment: @user1202717 you can order each group when enumerating them with `foreach(var h in g.OrderBy(x => x))`. Or you can select anonymous type instead of selecting group: `select new { Range = g.Key, Items = g.OrderBy(x => x) }` which will have range and ordered items

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: Any idea how to sort by date WITHIN the group?

Comment: @Romias `select g.OrderBy(x => x.EntryDate)`

Comment: For EF 6, need to use`DbFunctions.DiffDays` on the `daysFromToday` calculation. `let daysFromToday = DbFunctions.DiffDays(h.EntryDate, today)`

Answer (score 5):

How about doing this?

Introduce a new property for grouping and group by that.

```
class ListHeaderData
{
    public DateTime EntryDate;
    public int DateDifferenceFromToday
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Today - EntryDate.Date;
            if (difference.TotalDays == 0)//today
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (difference.TotalDays <= 14)//less than 2 weeks
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else
            {
                return 3;//something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: as @servy pointed in comments other developers may confuse of `int` using a `enum` will be more readable.

So, modified version of your class would look something like this

```
class ListHeaderData
{
    public DateTime EntryDate;
    public DateRange DateDifferenceFromToday
    {
        get
        {
            //I think for this version no comments needed names are self explanatory
            TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Today - EntryDate.Date;
            if (difference.TotalDays == 0)
            {
                return DateRange.Today;
            }
            else if (difference.TotalDays <= 14)
            {
                return DateRange.LessThanTwoWeeks;
            }
            else
            {
                return DateRange.MoreThanTwoWeeks;
            }
        }
    }
}

enum DateRange
{ 
    None = 0,
    Today = 1,
    LessThanTwoWeeks = 2,
    MoreThanTwoWeeks = 3
}
```

and use it like this

```
 var defaultGroups = from l in ListHeader
     group l by l.DateDifferenceFromToday into g // <--Note group by DateDifferenceFromToday
     orderby g.Min(x => x.EntryDate)
     select new { GroupBy = g };
```

Comment: @JimBallard Just saw your profile. OMG 30+ yrs of experience in software? am not yet crossed 30 age!

Comment: Ha! My first code was on punch cards fed into an IBM 360. The 360 was brand new and cutting edge!

Comment: I would avoid using an `int` for this; the reader of the code will have no idea what it means.  Use something like an `enum` for this; it's all the same to a computer, but it'll be *much* more readable.  Also, there's no reason to create a new anonymous type just to put the group in it.  If you only need the group just select out the group.

Comment: @Servy yes anonymous type is redundant here, I just copied OP's code. I'll consider enum in my answer

Comment: @Servy Updated with an enumeration. I hope now it looks more readable

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i cant hard code any data. I hard coded data for sample purposes. I have no idea how many dates the service will be returning, so I need the grouping,sorting ad counting done in LINq

Comment: You shouldn't be comparing `TotalDays` to `0` to get "today".  It's a `double`; it'll have a fractional day for any partial day.  You want less than one instead

Comment: @user1202717 So your date ranges are dynamic?  If so, how do you know what they are?

Comment: @Servy No, you have to note `DateTime.Today - EntryDate.Date` So fractional part is ignored here precision is upto date only. I can reliably compare `TotalDays` to `0`

Comment: My date ranges will be in forms like (last 2 weeks, last month, last year). So The service will return dates in the range selected, then I need them grouped, sorted and counted. Im dealing with a lot of data, so there will be alot of dates returned.

Comment: @user1202717 You still haven't described how to determine what group an item belongs in, for a person let alone a computer.  You need to start there.

Comment: So you're defining `last 2 weeks, last month, last year` etc right? define the same in enum and modify property accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically want to achieve the solution in this way? Also do you really want to introduce spurious properties into your class to meet these requirements?

These three lines would achieve your requirements and for large collections willbe more performant.

```
var todays = listHeader.Where(item => item.EntryDate == DateTime.Today);

var twoWeeks = listHeader.Where(item => item.EntryDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) 
                                && item.EntryDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14));

var later = listHeader.Where(item => item.EntryDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14));
```

also you then get the flexibility of different groupings without impacting your class.

**[Edit: in response to ordering query]**

Making use of the Enum supplied above you can apply the Union clause and OrderBy clause Linq extension methods as follows:

```
var ord = todays.Select(item => new {Group = DateRange.Today, item.EntryDate})
          .Union(
          twoWeeks.Select(item => new {Group = DateRange.LessThanTwoWeeks, item.EntryDate}))
          .Union(
          later.Select(item => new {Group = DateRange.MoreThanTwoWeeks, item.EntryDate}))
          .OrderBy(item => item.Group);
```

Note that I'm adding the Grouping via a Linq Select and anonymous class to dynamically push a Group property again not effecting the original class. This produces the following output based on the original post:

```
Group            EntryDate
Today            17/09/2013 00:00:00
LessThanTwoWeeks 11/09/2013 00:00:00
LessThanTwoWeeks 15/09/2013 00:00:00 
LessThanTwoWeeks 05/09/2013 00:00:00 
MoreThanTwoWeeks 26/08/2013 00:00:00 
MoreThanTwoWeeks 01/01/2013 00:00:00
```

and to get grouped date ranges with count:

```
var ord = todays.Select(item => new {Group = DateRange.Today, Count=todays.Count()})
          .Union(
          twoWeeks.Select(item => new {Group = DateRange.LessThanTwoWeeks, Count=twoWeeks.Count()}))
          .Union(
          later.Select(item => new {Group = DateRange.MoreThanTwoWeeks, Count=later.Count()}))
          .OrderBy(item => item.Group);
```

Output is:

```
Group            Count
Today            1 
LessThanTwoWeeks 3 
MoreThanTwoWeeks 2
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How do I sort (orderby) the groups?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this depends on how heavily you plan on using this. I had/have a lot of reports to generate so I created a model `IncrementDateRange` with `StartTime`, `EndTime` and `TimeIncrement` as an enum.

The time increment handler has a lot of switch based functions spits out a list of times between the Start and End range based on hour/day/week/month/quarter/year etc.

Then you get your list of `IncrementDateRange` and in linq something like either:

```
TotalsList = times.Select(t => new RetailSalesTotalsListItem()
{
    IncrementDateRange = t,
    Total = storeSales.Where(s => s.DatePlaced >= t.StartTime && s.DatePlaced <= t.EndTime).Sum(s => s.Subtotal),
})
```

or

```
TotalsList = storeSales.GroupBy(g => g.IncrementDateRange.StartTime).Select(gg => new RetailSalesTotalsListItem()
{
    IncrementDateRange = times.First(t => t.StartTime == gg.Key),
    Total = gg.Sum(rs => rs.Subtotal),
}).ToList(),
```