# C#- LINQ Grouping on a custom created date range

Tags: c#, linq

So, I have this `LINQ` query:

```
var Result = from u in Users 
             group u by new {u.AccountType, u.Id,u.CreationDate} into usergroup
             select new {id=usergroup.Key.Id,CreationDate=usergroup.Key.CreationDate,AccountType=usergroup.Key.AccountType};
```

that returns the following data set:

[image]

I am able to get the individual group count like this:

```
var myresult=Result.GroupBy(n=>n.AccountType).Select(n=>new {AccountType=n.Key,TotalCount=n.Count()});
```

which gives me:

[image]

Now suppose, I define a custom date range of `Months` from `January-December`, how can I do a group on the first data-set to give me count of `AccountType` based on each month based on the `CreationDate` column into my custom date range?

Comment: is that [post: LINQ & Grouping data by a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423512/linq-grouping-data-by-a-date-range) helpful?

Comment: or maybe [this one: Group by date range , count and sort within each group LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852172/group-by-date-range-count-and-sort-within-each-group-linq) ?

Comment: You can get a month from creation date and use it to group and filter

Comment: "Now suppose, I define a custom date range of Months from January-December" do you intend to filter before the grouping for this range?

Comment: @MongZhu I do not intended to filter on the date range but the actual filter will be applied on the account type (which is shown on a doughnut graph). I just need the dataset from 1-12 month with count of each account type in that month.

Comment: then i find the date range confusing, what is it good for?

Comment: @MongZhu The custom date range is only to group the data set into respective months. Once I have all the grouped data, then I can generate my graph on this. Once this is done, then I can filter them out on the account type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to understand what type you would like your result to be in. If you want a list of Months, each of which would have a tally of Accounts per AccountType, then you could try something like this:

```
var myResult2 = result.GroupBy(o => o.CreationDate.Month).Select(monthGroup => new
    {
        Month = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(monthGroup.Key),
        Accounts = monthGroup.GroupBy(o => o.AccountType).ToDictionary(accountGroup => accountGroup.Key, accountGroup => accountGroup.Count())
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this is only adding up to count of 13 whereas I have 40 elements in my data set.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "is only adding up to count 13"? There are 7 months in your dataset and each of them has multiple counts (one for each AccountType). The total of all of them should be 40...

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes you are right. Let me try it out.

Comment: @RahulSharma if this is your accepted answer, then the "custom" date range does not play any role. I don't see any consideration of it in here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I think this will do your job

```
.GroupBy(g => new { g.CreationDate.Date.Month, g.AccountType })
    .Select(t => new { t.Key.AccountType, t.Key.Month, Count = t.Count() });
```

Comment: How can I group on each month for all the account types? Can I have a dataset that only has 1-12 months with count of each account type?

Comment: This does group your dataset base on month and account type.If you need also for different years then you must group by year also.

Comment: @RahulSharma " Can I have a dataset that only has 1-12 months" there are no more months...

Answer (score 0):

I Have Try Below Code:

```
var data = Users.GroupBy(x => new {x.column1 , x.column2 ,...})
.Select(y=> new className() { column1 = y.Key.column1 , column2 = y.Key.column2}).ToList<className>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If CreationDate is a string:

```
var group = result.GroupBy(g => new { DateTime.Parse(g.CreationDate).Date.Month, g.AccountType })
                  .Select(user => new { user.Key.AccountType, user.Key.Month, Count = user.Count() });

foreach (var g in group)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Users with Month[{g.Month}] : {g.Count}, AccType: {g.AccountType};");
}
```